# onCreateViewHolder overrides nothing

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

```
class MainScreenAdapter(_songDetails: ArrayList<Songs>, _context: Context) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<MainScreenAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
var songDetails: ArrayList<Songs>? = null
var mContext: Context? = null
init {
    this.songDetails = _songDetails
    this.mContext = _context
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
val songObject = songDetails?.get(position)
    holder.trackTitle?.text = songObject?.songTitle
    holder.trackArtist?.text = songObject?.artist
    holder.contentHolder?.setOnClickListener({
        val songPlayingFragment = SongPlayingFragment()
        var args = Bundle()
        args.putString("songArtist", songObject?.artist)
        args.putString("path", songObject?.songData)
        args.putString("songTitle", songObject?.songTitle)
        args.putInt("SongId", songObject?.songID?.toInt() as Int)
        args.putInt("songPosition", position)
        args.putParcelableArrayList("songData", songDetails)
        (mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.details_fragment, songPlayingFragment)
            .commit()
    })}  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.row_custom_mainscreen_adapter, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}
  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    if (songDetails == null) {
        return 0
    } else {
        return (songDetails as ArrayList<Songs>).size
    }}class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var trackTitle: TextView? = null
    var trackArtist: TextView? = null
    var contentHolder: RelativeLayout? = null
     init {
        trackTitle = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.trackTitle)
        trackArtist = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.trackArtist)
        contentHolder = view.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.contentRow)
   }}}
```

For:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder
```

why it is showing **override nothing**?

also for:

```
class MainScreenAdapter(_songDetails: ArrayList, _context: Context)
```

It says **its not abstract and does not implement abstract base class members**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `onCreateViewHolder()` is wrong:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int)
```

remove `?` after `ViewGroup`:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)
```

---

From `RecyclerView.class`, the signature of `onCreateViewHolder()` 
which you must override is this:

```
@NonNull
public abstract VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup var1, int var2);
```

as you can see the 1st parameter `ViewGroup var1` is not nullable.